# C++20 Coroutines, Unexpected reordering of await_resume, return_value and yield_value

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

**Background**

I have a task type that can both `co_return` and `co_yield`.
In LLVM the task works as expected and passes some early tests. In MSVC and GCC the code fails in the same manner (coincidence?).

---

**Brief Problem**

With the following test function:

```
Task<int> test_yielding()
{
    co_yield 1;
    co_return 2;
}
```

There are two values retrieved from a Task object.

```
auto a = co_await fn;
auto b = co_await fn;
```

The value of a is expected to be 1, the value of b is expected to be 2.

The result is tested against `a + b == 3`.

The above test passes, however the following test fails:

```
auto res = co_await fn + co_await fn
```

The value of res for GCC and MSVC is 4. Both retrieved from the final co_return. As I understand it the first and second calls of `co_await fn` should be 1 and 2 in either order.

In MSVC and GCC the code fails as they seems to reorder `await_resume`, `return_value` and `yield_value`.

---

**Details**

I have run the code through clang tidy, PVS studio, enabled all the available sanitisers in LLVM, GCC, MSVC and nothing relevant pops up (just comments about destroy and resume not being noexcept).

I have several very similar tests:
The relevant tests are:

Function:

```
Task<int> test_yielding()
{
    co_yield 1;
    co_return 2;
}
```

Test 1 (PASS):

```
Title("Test co_yield + co_return lvalue");
auto fn = test_yielding();
auto a = co_await fn;
auto b = co_await fn;
ASSERT(a + b == 3);
```

Test 2 (FAIL):

```
Title("Test co_yield + co_return rvalue");
auto fn = test_yielding();
auto res =
(
    co_await fn +
    co_await fn
);
ASSERT(res == 3);
```

The result of the test MSVC 1 (PASS):

```
---------------------------------
Title   Test co_yield + co_return lvalue
---------------------------------
        get_return_object: 02F01DA0
        initial_suspend: 02F01DA0
        await_transform: 02D03C80
        AwaitAwaitable: await_ready: 02F01DA0
        AwaitAwaitable: await_suspend: 02F01DA0
        SetCurrent: 02F01DA0
        ContinueWith: 02F01DA0
        yield_value: 02F01DA0
        SetValue: 02F01DA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_ready: 02F01DA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_suspend: 02F01DA0
        ContinueWith: 02F01DA0
        AwaitAwaitable: await_resume: 02F01DA0
        GetValue: 02F01DA0
        await_transform: 02D03C80
        AwaitAwaitable: await_ready: 02F01DA0
        AwaitAwaitable: await_suspend: 02F01DA0
        SetCurrent: 02F01DA0
        ContinueWith: 02F01DA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_resume: 02F01DA0
        return_value: 02F01DA0
        SetValue: 02F01DA0
        final_suspend: 02F01DA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_ready: 02F01DA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_suspend: 02F01DA0
        ContinueWith: 02F01DA0
        AwaitAwaitable: await_resume: 02F01DA0
        GetValue: 02F01DA0
PASS    test_task:323 a + b == 3
        [ result = 3, expected = 3 ]
        Destroy: 02F01DA0
```

The result of the test MSVC 2 (FAIL):

```
---------------------------------
Title   Test co_yield + co_return rvalue
---------------------------------
        get_return_object: 02F01CA0
        initial_suspend: 02F01CA0
        await_transform: 02D03C80
        AwaitAwaitable: await_ready: 02F01CA0
        AwaitAwaitable: await_suspend: 02F01CA0
        SetCurrent: 02F01CA0
        ContinueWith: 02F01CA0
        yield_value: 02F01CA0
        SetValue: 02F01CA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_ready: 02F01CA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_suspend: 02F01CA0
        ContinueWith: 02F01CA0
        await_transform: 02D03C80
        AwaitAwaitable: await_ready: 02F01CA0
        AwaitAwaitable: await_suspend: 02F01CA0
        SetCurrent: 02F01CA0
        ContinueWith: 02F01CA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_resume: 02F01CA0
        return_value: 02F01CA0
        SetValue: 02F01CA0
        final_suspend: 02F01CA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_ready: 02F01CA0
        YieldAwaitable: await_suspend: 02F01CA0
        ContinueWith: 02F01CA0
        AwaitAwaitable: await_resume: 02F01CA0
        GetValue: 02F01CA0
        AwaitAwaitable: await_resume: 02F01CA0
        GetValue: 02F01CA0
FAIL    test_task:342 res == 3
        [ result = 4, expected = 3 ]
        Destroy: 02F01CA0
```

If you look at the diff between working MSVC FAIL and MSVC PASS (with addresses corrected, the following appears):
[image]
Which makes it clear that the following lines were reordered:

```
        AwaitAwaitable: await_resume: 02901E20  
        GetValue: 02901E20
```

The source and results for LLVM and GCC are [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7rn5jz).

Looking at the test 2 diff between the GCC FAIL and LLVM PASS:
[image: GCC vs LLVM]
A very similar reording is occuring in GCC.

The highlighted lines in the diff are produced be the following source:

```
template <typename Promise>
struct AwaitAwaitable
{
    Promise & m_promise;

    bool await_ready() const noexcept
    {
        WriteLine("AwaitAwaitable: ", __func__, ": ", &m_promise);
        return false;
    }

    void await_suspend(default_handle handle) noexcept
    {
        WriteLine("AwaitAwaitable: ", __func__, ": ", &m_promise);
        m_promise.SetCurrent( m_promise.Handle() );
        m_promise.ContinueWith( handle );
    }

    auto await_resume() const noexcept
    {
        WriteLine("AwaitAwaitable: ", __func__, ": ", &m_promise);
        return m_promise.GetValue();
    }
};
```

Does anybody know what is going on here, is this a compiler/library/user error?

Comment: A compiler is allowed to evaluate both `co_await fn` before retrieving the value and adding them. And since both store the result in the same `Task<int>` then it gets overwritten with the last value (2 in this case). While `auto a = co_await fn` copies the result after the first `co_await`. I think that's what is happening. AFAIK the result of `(co_await fn + co_await fn)` line is not well defined.

Comment: Would that be a defect report? 
That sounds like really unintunitive behaviour. 
Isn't that expession equivilent to `(co_await fn) + (co_await fn)` (which also doesn't work). It doesn't seem like a work around would exist in that case (unless I use dynamic storage to store all results, but thats really impractical and inefficient).

I made the storage volatile, it still doesn't work, which implies reordering of volatile reads and writes (not allowed). It should be write-read-write-read, but its write-write-read-read.

Comment: I don't think this is related to volatile. Consider `f() + f()` where `f` has signature `int& f()`. Even if `f()` uses locks and stores the result in shared memory, reordering is still allowed (after all, generally, the compiler doesn't know whether f() internally forces some memory ordering or not). This is pretty much what happens since the state/result of a coroutine is shared between the coroutine and its caller. AFAIK co_await itself does not force memory ordering. I might be wrong though, I don't have much experience with coroutines in C++.

Comment: And yes, reordering and sequence points are counterintuitive and evil. :/

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be something like that. But couldn't believe that co_await would allow that. Like, I don't think its unreasonable for reordering of the full expression (from a + b to b + a), but I don't think its reasonable to reorder the resume.

Comment: foo() + bar() may be reordered, but as I understand it, it can only be reordered so that bar or foo is evaluated first (not reordered half way through execution of foo).

Comment: They can be interleaved, i.e. [eval foo()] -> [eval bar()] -> [read foo() result] -> [read bar() result] is possible. At least that's how I understand https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order "Ordering" section: "they may be performed in any order and may overlap"

Comment: Hmm, although rule 11 contradicts this. At least for normal function calls. However I couldn't find anything about `co_await` in the standard regarding ordering. I suppose this is UB at the moment.

Comment: Well thats unreal, such a simple expression. This needs to be fixed :|

Comment: This is core issue 2466 (not yet on a public issue list).

Comment: It is now in the public issues list:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2466

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The observed behaviour appears to be due to similar bugs in both GCC and MSVC in their handling of the addition-operator where the arguments are both `co_await` expressions.

- [GCC Bug Report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97452)
- [MSVC Bug Report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1220728/c20-coroutines-unexpected-reordering-of-await-resu.html)

In this instance, both GCC and MSVC seem to be incorrectly sequencing the call to `await_resume()` for both `co_await` expressions after resumption from the second suspend-point (ie. just before the addition is performed).

They should instead be sequencing the call to `await_resume()` for the first `co_await` expression (it is indeterminate which one) immediately after resuming from the first suspend-point and before beginning to evaluate the second `co_await` expression.

Comment: Thanks a bunch lewis and thanks for cppcoro!
I've been trying to get this issue some attention. 
My GCC report is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97433

Comment: Where does the standard say that this is incorrect?

Comment: Just replacing my comment with a better link :)
https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#9

Comment: Section [expr.await] p5.2 states:
> If the result of await-ready is true, or when the coroutine is resumed, the await-resume expression is evaluated, and its result is the result of the await-expression.

This to me implies the await-expression is evaluated immediately when the coroutine is resumed.

But if we read it with respect to [intro.execution] p10, which says that sub-expressions are unsequenced unless otherwise specified, and [expr.add] which doesn't specify any sequencing for builtin operator+ arguments, then it's possible compilers might treat co_await parts as unsequenced...?

Comment: If it treats the as unsequenced, do you think that's a defect?

Comment: Yes, I think that should be a defect - if that interpretation of the spec is correct.

Comment: If it were possible to store the result efficiently in the awaitable, there would be a reasonable work around, but since return_value and yield_value are inside promise its going to be somewhat inefficient :(

Comment: @DavidLedger: What happens if you return a prvalue instead of a reference?

Comment: I believe I do return prvalue, no luck :( See line 153 of this https://godbolt.org/z/xevhv9 ). I've tried both ref categories, no luck. I also tried all the value categories on the argument of return_value and yield_value, no luck. I also tried [[gnu::noinline]] and [[gnu::no_reorder]] which amazingly didn't work...