# Order of calls in aggregate initialization over a co_await statement

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

I was tracking down a bug in gcc and encountered a situation for which I don't know what the acceptable behavior(s) are. Suppose we have, somewhere within a coroutine, a line such as:

```
Pair{.x{}, .y=(co_await std::suspend_always{}, 1)};
```

where `Pair` is some struct that can be aggregate initialized with members `.x` (of type `X` with a default constructor) and `.y` (with of type `Y` with a constructor from an int). These types may all have nontrivial destructors. What may this code do?

---

Section 9.4.1/6 of the C++20 standard states:

> The initializations of the elements of the aggregate are evaluated in the element order. That is, all value computations and side effects associated with a given element are sequenced before those of any element that
> follows it in order.

which suggests to me that the **only** correct behavior for this line is as follows:

1. Reserve space in the coroutine frame for an object of type `Pair`.
2. Initialize the `.x` member via a call to `X::X()`
3. Evaluate the `co_await` expression (calling `await_ready` and `await_suspend`); suspend.

Then, if the coroutine is resumed, I expect:

4. Call `await_resume` on the awaiter.
5. Initialize the `.y` member via a call to `Y::Y(int)`
6. Call `Pair::~Pair()` to destroy the temporary.

If the coroutine is instead destroyed, I expect:

4. Call `X::~X()` on the `.x` member.

I'm fairly sure that this is correct behavior, though less sure whether it's the only allowable behavior - and my confusion is worsened by the fact that none of the major compilers output sensible code for this case. A full example [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dz1818naf) shows that both gcc and clang produce code where calls to destructors and constructors are not properly matched (which is the bug I was hunting down in gcc in the first place). MSVC gives an internal compiler error.

Is the suggested behavior correct? Is this the only correct behavior?

Comment: This perhaps related to core issue: www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2466. My question dealt with a similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64348125/c20-coroutines-unexpected-reordering-of-await-resume-return-value-and-yield

Answer (score -2):

In the specific code you provided:

1. Reserve space in the coroutine frame for an object of type Pair
2. Initialize the .x member via a call to X::X() (assuming X has a
   default constructor).
3. Evaluate the co_await expression (calling
   await_ready and await_suspend); suspend.
4. If the coroutine is
   resumed:

   - Call await_resume on the awaiter.
   - Initialize the .y member
     via a call to Y::Y(int).
   - Call Pair::~Pair() to destroy the
     temporary.
5. If the coroutine is instead destroyed:

   - Call X::~X() on
     the .x member.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <coroutine>
    
    struct X {
        X() { std::cout << "X::X()\n"; }
        ~X() { std::cout << "X::~X()\n"; }
    };
    
    struct Y {
        Y(int) { std::cout << "Y::Y(int)\n"; }
        ~Y() { std::cout << "Y::~Y()\n"; }
    };
    
    struct Pair {
        X x;
        Y y;
    };
    
    struct Awaiter {
        bool await_ready() { return false; }
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<>) {}
        void await_resume() {}
    };
    
    struct Coroutine {
        struct promise_type {
            Promise* get_return_object() { return nullptr; }
            std::suspend_always initial_suspend() { return {}; }
            std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
            void return_void() {}
            void unhandled_exception() {}
        };
    
        using promise_type = promise_type;
    
        std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;
    
        Coroutine(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) : handle(h) {}
        ~Coroutine() {
            if (handle)
                handle.destroy();
        }
    };
    
    Coroutine createCoroutine() {
        co_await std::suspend_always{};
        co_return;
    }
    
    int main() {
        Coroutine coroutine = createCoroutine();
        std::cout << "Coroutine created\n";
        coroutine.handle.resume();
        std::cout << "Coroutine resumed\n";
        coroutine.handle.destroy();
        std::cout << "Coroutine destroyed\n";
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what this is supposed to show? OP tagged `language-lawyer`, meaning they're looking for a quote from the standard explaining how this is supposed to behave.